# How do I prevent only the page turn event in Ibooks fixed layout book?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, epub, ibooks

I'm trying to create a stop/start button for an ibooks read-aloud fixed layout  book, and I want to prevent the page from turning at the location of this button. The HTML element is as follows.

```
<p ibooks:readaloud="startstop" id="rass" ontouchstart="prevent(event)">SS</p>
```

The javascript is as follows.

```
function prevent(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

So ibooks:readaloud attribute makes the read aloud start and stop when the p tag is touched, however, preventing default behavior of on touch also prevents the behavior of the ibooks:read aloud attribute.

Is there a way for me to manually start and stop the read aloud, or to prevent only the page turn?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your HTML file:

```
<p ibooks:readaloud="startstop" id="rass">&#x2735;</p>
```

And put this into your CSS file:

```
html p#raplay {
    top: 955px;
    left: 700px;
    color: green;
    padding: 0px 6px 0 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

 html p#rastop {
    top: 955px;
    left: 700px;
    padding: 0px 6px 0 10px;
    color: red;
    display: none;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;

}

html p#rass {
    top: 955px;
    left: 700px;
    padding: 2px 6px 4px 8px;
    color: green;
    background: white;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

html.-ibooks-media-overlay-enabled p#raplay {
   display: none;
   }
html.-ibooks-media-overlay-enabled p#rastop {
display: block;
}
```

if that p tag click, the read aloud will stop. that is the default of the read aloud. you dont need to use javascript.